# Remove color option from second element in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot where I first fit a melted table with a `geom_line` using the `color:variable` to colour the diffrent lines.

When I then try to fit a second element, namely a `geom_ribbon`. I then get the error message:

**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found**

Why is that? I'm not using it in the second element. A sub-optimal workaround is to overwrite with color=NA in the ribbon geom but this produces a black line around my ribbon which I don't want..

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=as.Date(date), y=value, group=variable, color=variable)) + 
geom_line() +
geom_ribbon(data=fitted, aes(x=as.Date(date), y=forecast, ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill="black", group=1), alpha=.2,  fill="red")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have set `color=variable` in `aes()` of `ggplot()` call then `geom_ribbon()` also tries to use `variable` for the color. Add `inherit.aes=FALSE` inside `geom_ribbon()` to ensure that previously set aesthetics are not used.